# Access data into list of dictionaries python

Tags: python, dictionary, nested-loops

I have a list of dictionaries, with some nested dictionaries inside:

```
[{'id': '67569006',
'kind': 'analytics#accountSummary',
'name': 'Adopt-a-Hydrant',
'webProperties': [{'id': 'UA-62536006-1',
                 'internalWebPropertyId': '102299473',
                 'kind': 'analytics#webPropertySummary',
                 'level': 'STANDARD',
                 'name': 'Adopt-a-Hydrant',
                 'profiles': [{'id': '107292146',
                               'kind': 'analytics#profileSummary',
                               'name': 'Adopt a Hydrant view1',
                               'type': 'WEB'},
                              {'id': '1372982608',
                               'kind': 'analytics#profileSummary',
                               'name': 'Unfiltered view',
                               'type': 'WEB'}],
                 'websiteUrl': 'https://example1.com/'}]},
{'id': '44824959',
'kind': 'analytics#accountSummary',
'name': 'Adorn',
'webProperties': [{'id': 'UA-62536006-1',
                 'internalWebPropertyId': '75233390',
                 'kind': 'analytics#webPropertySummary',
                 'level': 'STANDARD',
                 'name': 'Website 2',
                 'profiles': [{'id': '77736192',
                               'kind': 'analytics#profileSummary',
                               'name': 'All Web Site Data',
                               'type': 'WEB'}],
                 'websiteUrl': 'http://www.example2.com'}]},
]
```

I'm trying to print the site name, url & view, if the site have 2 or more views print them all, and this is where it gets tricky.

So far I've tried:

```
all_properties = [The list above]
for single_property in all_properties:
    single_propery_name=single_property['name']
    view_name=single_property['webProperties'][0]['profiles'][0]['name']
    view_id=single_property['webProperties'][0]['profiles'][0]['id']
    print(single_propery_name, view_name, view_id)
```

This almost work, but it prints only the first view `profile>name` of each property, however some properties have more than one view and I need also these views to get print out.

The output now is:

```
Adopt-a-Hydrant Adopt a Hydrant view1 107292146
Website 2 All Web Site Data 77736192
```

So it's skipping the second view of the first property. I tried nesting a sub for loop but I can't get it to work, the final output should be:

```
Adopt-a-Hydrant Adopt a Hydrant view1 107292146
Adopt-a-Hydrant Unfiltered View 1372982608
Website 2 All Web Site Data 77736192
```

Any ideas on how to get that?

Comment: Since the `['webProperties'][0]['profiles']` will always be a `list`, you can try looping over that too. Just add another `for` loop where you do  `view_name`.

Comment: Is the number of "profiles" considered the number of views?

Comment: I tried with an extra for loop like this:


    `for single_property in all_properties:`
    `single_propery_name=single_property['name']`
    `view_name=single_property['webProperties'][0]['profiles'][0]['name']`
    `for each_view in single_property['webProperties'][0]['profiles'][0]['name']:`
       `print(each_view)`


But I'm still not getting there..

Comment: @nfnneil yes correct

Comment: Finally responded, sorry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to iterate through the profiles list for each `single_property`:

```
for single_property in all_properties:
    single_property_name = single_property['name']
    for profile in single_property['webProperties'][0]['profiles']:
            view_name = profile['name']
            view_id = profile['id']
            print(single_property_name, view_name, view_id)
```

It would probably help if you read a little in the [python docs](https://docs.python.org/3/) about lists and how to iterate through them

Answer (score 0):

Just another proposition with oneline loops:

```
for single_property in data:
   single_propery_name=single_property['name']
   view_name = [i['name'] for i in single_property['webProperties'][0]['profiles']]
   view_id = [i['id'] for i in single_property['webProperties'][0]['profiles']]
   print(single_propery_name, view_name, view_id)
```

The point is that you will have to loop inside the lists. You could also make objects, if you think your Data would be more manageable.

Answer (score 0):

If you're getting really confused, don't be afraid to just make variable.

Look at how much more readable this is:

```
for item in data:
    webProperties = item['webProperties'][0]
    print("Name: " + webProperties["name"])
    print("URL: " + webProperties["websiteUrl"])
    print("PRINTING VIEWS\n")
    print("----------------------------")
    views = webProperties['profiles']
    for view in views:
        print("ID: " + view['id'])
        print("Kind: " + view['kind'])
        print("Name: " + view['name'])
        print("Type: " + view['type'])
    print("----------------------------")
    print("\n\n\n")
```

Data is defined as the information you gave us:

```
data = [{'id': '67569006',
'kind': 'analytics#accountSummary',
'name': 'Adopt-a-Hydrant',
'webProperties': [{'id': 'UA-62536006-1',
                 'internalWebPropertyId': '102299473',
                 'kind': 'analytics#webPropertySummary',
                 'level': 'STANDARD',
                 'name': 'Adopt-a-Hydrant',
                 'profiles': [{'id': '107292146',
                               'kind': 'analytics#profileSummary',
                               'name': 'Adopt a Hydrant view1',
                               'type': 'WEB'},
                              {'id': '1372982608',
                               'kind': 'analytics#profileSummary',
                               'name': 'Unfiltered view',
                               'type': 'WEB'}],
                 'websiteUrl': 'https://example1.com/'}]},
{'id': '44824959',
'kind': 'analytics#accountSummary',
'name': 'Adorn',
'webProperties': [{'id': 'UA-62536006-1',
                 'internalWebPropertyId': '75233390',
                 'kind': 'analytics#webPropertySummary',
                 'level': 'STANDARD',
                 'name': 'Website 2',
                 'profiles': [{'id': '77736192',
                               'kind': 'analytics#profileSummary',
                               'name': 'All Web Site Data',
                               'type': 'WEB'}],
                 'websiteUrl': 'http://www.example2.com'}]},
]
```